# The JPA query is not working

Tags: jpa

what is the query to get userid out of the table?

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `UPLOADIMAGE` 
(
    `IMAGE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `FILE_DATA` tinyblob,
    `FILE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `FILE_PATH` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `USER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IMAGE_ID`),
    KEY `FKC057C7DA8B4610BF` (`USER_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKC057C7DA8B4610BF` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `USER` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and here is my java code to get the userid:

```
public int showUserImageId(int userid)
{
    String askedQuery="select u.USER_ID from UPLOADIMAGE u where u.USER_ID = :id";
    TypedQuery<UploadImage> query =   
        entityManager.createQuery(askedQuery,UploadImage.class);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    query.setParameter("id", userid);
    int out= query.getSingleResult().getUser().getUserid();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return out;
}
```

And my UploadImage entity is:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="UPLOADIMAGE")
   public class UploadImage
    {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="IMAGE_ID")
private int imageid;

@Column(name="FILE_NAME")
private String fileName;


@Column(name="FILE_PATH")
private String filePath;

@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.DETACH)
private User user;

@Column(name="FILE_DATA")
private CommonsMultipartFile FileData;
     }
```

and the error I get is:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UPLOADIMAGE is not mapped [select  u.USER_ID from   UPLOADIMAGE u where u.USER_ID = :id]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:292)
at se.datalayer.guards.service.ImageUploadService.showUserImageId(ImageUploadService.java:162)
at se.datalayer.guards.main.Main.getUserIdFromImage(Main.java:70)
at se.datalayer.guards.main.Main.main(Main.java:48)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UPLOADIMAGE is not mapped [select  u.USER_ID from UPLOADIMAGE u where u.USER_ID = :id]
at  org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:315)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3357)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3241)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:726)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:577)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:294)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:237)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:277)
... 3 more
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Apart from the error on table name already pointed out by @JB, the line `int out= query.getSingleResult().getUser().getUserid();` is wrong, the result of the query is an `int` and not an `UploadImage` object, so you can't call `getUser()` on it. The correct query should be `select u.user from UploadImage u where u.user.id = :id`

Comment: Hi
Still the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the new query?

Comment: According to answer by JB Nizet the query would work : 
select u.userId from UploadImage u where u.userId = :userId
But nothing happens.

Comment: That query works but you cannot access the result with `int out= query.getSingleResult().getUser().getUserid();`, you should use `int out=query.getSingleResult();`, anyway it doesn't make any sense querying a value that you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL doesn't use tables and columns. It uses JPA entities and their persistent fields. So, to use a JPQL query, you would need a JPA entity `UploadImage`, mapped to your table, and containing persistent fields (imageId, userId, filePath, etc.).

The query would then look like

```
select u.userId from UploadImage u where u.userId = :userId
```

JPA is an ORM: Object Relational Mapper. The whole point is to be able to use objects rather than relational data.

That said, I don't really see the point of getting a user ID from the database, using this user ID as parameter.

Comment: Hi 
I have an entity UploadImage and I actually want the hole user.
But what I really want to do is, show the image of the user how logs in and therefor I use the userid to check if those two userid are the same. Still get the same error.

Comment: You're still using column names and table names in your query, instead of properties and entity names.